# Android web service not parsing data from localhost

Tags: php, android, json, localhost

I am trying to connect Android App to java webservice to get pHp parsed values.

Php Script is :

```
<?php
$data = array('name' => 'Froyo', 'version' => 'Android 2.2'); 
print (json_encode($data)); 
?>
```

And the Java WebService is :

```
package com.json.php;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import android.widget.TextView;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;


public class JSONExampleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost("http://127.0.0.1/test.php");
        TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        try {

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            String jsonResult = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent()).toString();
            JSONObject object = new JSONObject(jsonResult);

            String name = object.getString("name");
            String verion = object.getString("version");
            textView.setText(name + " - " + verion);

        } 
        catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


       }
    private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
        String rLine = "";
        StringBuilder answer = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

        try {
         while ((rLine = rd.readLine()) != null) {
          answer.append(rLine);
           }
        }

        catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
         }
        return answer;
       }
}
```

I tried both `http://127.0.0.1/test.php and http://localhost/test.php` in HttpPost, It doesn't works.
I checked my php file on the browser and that gives the result fine.
Where am i Going wrong?
Also i am working on a Mac, is that anyway related to the problem because of all the permission issues?

Comment: Are you on a emulator?

Comment: @silentw yes i am on an emulator

Comment: Try using `10.0.2.2` instead of 127.0.0.1. If you are using MAMP, maybe you need to add the port to the ip (defaults `10.0.2.2:8888`)

Comment: @silentw 10.0.2.2 worked! Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just take a look at this page : http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses

You'll notice that they refer to:

- `10.0.2.2` as Special alias to your host loopback interface (i.e.,
  127.0.0.1 on your development machine)
- `127.0.0.1` as The emulated device's own loopback interface

Hope I answered and solved your problem :)

Answer (score 1):

You should not use 127.0.0.1 or localhost because Android emulator runs inside a Virtual Machine(QEMU) therefore here 127.0.0.1 or localhost will be emulator's own loopback address.

If you are referring your localhost on your system from the Android emulator then you have to use `http://10.0.2.2/`. If the webservice is not on your development machine then use your server IP.

If your server is windows run the command "ipconfig" from command prompt to find the IP Address.

Refer: [Emulator Networking](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#emulatornetworking)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @silentw.. i figured out how to make it work!
just changed the HttpPost to `http://10.0.2.2/test.php`